# Using an ordinal scale ('d3.scale.ordinal') for the x-axis in a bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart, dc.js, crossfilter

I have a data array like this:

```
var data = [{"Alphabet_Type":"a"}, {"Alphabet_Type":"b"}, {"Alphabet_Type":"a"}];
```

I am using:

- dc.js
- crossfilter.js
- d3.js

I want to create a **bar chart** with:

- the x-axis having an alphabet name, and
- the y-axis having number of occurrences of the alphabet.

**Question:** How can I plot a bar chart with an **ordinal scale** on the x-axis?

My code:

```js
var data = [{"Alphabet_Type":"a"}, {"Alphabet_Type":"b"}, {"Alphabet_Type":"a"}];

var Filter = crossfilter(data);
var Dimension = Filter.dimension(function (d) { return d.Alphabet_Type; });
var Group = Dimension.group();

dc.barChart("#bar-chart")
    .width(800) 
    .height(275) 
    .transitionDuration(0) 
    .margins({ top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 40 })
    .dimension(Dimension) 
    .group(Group) 
    .elasticY(false)
    .elasticX(false)
    .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([-1, 10]))
    .y(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 5]))
    .centerBar(true)
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    .renderVerticalGridLines(true)
    .brushOn(false);
```

Finally, I have another problem which is that `Alphabet_Type` is not going to have predictable values. So I need to fetch the values for `Alphabet_Type` via **crossfilter.js** and incorporate those values into the domain. How can I do this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Two things:

1. Pass [`dc.units.ordinal`](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#dcunitsordinal) as the parameter to [`.xUnits()`](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#xunitsxunits-function).
2. Pass an **ordinal scale** function to [`.x()`](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#xxscale---mandatory).

Here's what I mean:

```js
.x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["", "a", "b", "c"])) // Need empty val to offset first value
.xUnits(dc.units.ordinal) // Tell dc.js that we're using an ordinal x-axis
```

See this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/reblace/tbamW/156/

For some reason, I couldn't get [`renderHorizontalGridLines()`](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#renderhorizontalgridlinesboolean) or [`renderVerticalGridLines()`](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#renderverticalgridlinesboolean) to work, but the rest is good.

Comment: Thanks @reblace for your answer. it works well. I have edited my question. Please help me in this. since am new to dc i dont know to implement this.

Comment: I got the answer for the question i added. Now how to add a "" (blank string) like u have added in thje domain by using the function.

Comment: the .xUnits() part was what was missing and cost me a tone of time. Thank you, it finally bloody works.

Comment: the .xUnits() part was what was missing and cost me a tone of time. Thank you, it finally bloody works. Exactly!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                          .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal) // Tell Dc.js that we're using an ordinal x axis

Comment: The domain is computed automatically for ordinal x scales in dc.js 2.0 and later.

Comment: Not sure if it happens to every one.. when tried to offset with blank string, I got the whole x axis lines offset. Not sure if this is trivial, let me know I will post a fiddle.

Comment: Wow, `.xUnits` was hard to find! It doesn't show up in many examples, but it was exactly what I needed. I'm using it with `.x(d3.time.scale())` and it works like a charm there too.

Answer (score 7):

Adding

```js
.x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(data.map(function (d) {return d.Alphabet_Type; })))
```

solved the problem.