# dc.js: Setting Categorical Bar Chart X Axis with a Wide Domain

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I have a csv with a column that is a category variable that I want to set on the x Axis of a dashboard using dc.js

I know that I can set the set the x-axis as this (copied from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18742406/d3-scale-ordinal-x-axis-in-a-bar-chart))

```
.x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["", "a", "b", "c"])) // Need empty val to offset first value
.xUnits(dc.units.ordinal) // Tell Dc.js that we're using an ordinal x axis
```

However, is there any way I can replace the `a`,`b`, and `c` with a variable that captures all of this? My column has 20 different categories and I don't want to type them out by hand. My code is below (the column is `d.geo`)

```
var geoValue = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
    return d.geo;
});
var geoGroup = geoValue.group();

geoChart
    .width(960)
    .height(150)
    .margins({top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40})
    .dimension(geoValue)
    .group(geoGroup)
    .transitionDuration(500)
    .gap(10)
    .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(SOLUTION GOES HERE))
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .elasticY(true)
    .xAxis().tickFormat();
```

Comment: As of dc.js 2.0, ordinal domains are calculated automatically.

Comment: You do not need to call `.domain()` at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should work

```
.x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(geoValue))
```

the following worked for me. I was also struggling with a similar scenario

```
var carTypeDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d["car-type"]; });
carTypeGroup = carTypeDim.group()

carTypeChartBar
  .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(carTypeDim)) 
  .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
  .dimension(carTypeDim)
  .group(carTypeGroup);
```